# Wordpress wp_insert_post function

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a php program to insert a wordpress post using wordpress functions. When I use the function `wp_insert_post()`, any `<script>` tags in my post content are removed. Is there is a way to override this in Wordpress?

Comment: any SCRIPT tags in my content are removed.

Comment: It might be a security thing.

Comment: I fixed it using a work around. I ended up writing a function in my theme with a SHORT CODE and used the Short code when publishing the post. SHORT CODE gets replaced with the script at the time of rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by pp19dd doesn't work anymore in newer versions of WordPress. The new way, as suggested by a WordPress developer (but not recommended, because of security issues):

> filter had to be unset due to security problems with it. You could try doing kses_remove_filters() before inserting the post and kses_init_filters() after inserting the post if you are trying to avoid the kses filtering of the post fields. Just be wary since that defeats most of the security measures for inserting posts.

So:

```php
kses_remove_filters();
wp_insert_post( $postdata );
kses_init_filters();
```

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bypass-sanitize_post-from-wp_insert_post